# RBM implementation with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement RBM with tensorflow, here is the code:

**rbm.py**

```
""" An rbm implementation for TensorFlow, based closely on the one in Theano """
import tensorflow as tf
import math
def sample_prob(probs):
    return tf.nn.relu(
        tf.sign(
            probs - tf.random_uniform(probs.get_shape())))
class RBM(object):
    def __init__(self, name, input_size, output_size):
        with tf.name_scope("rbm_" + name):
            self.weights = tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([input_size, output_size],
                    stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(input_size))), name="weights")
            self.v_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_size]), name="v_bias")
            self.h_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]), name="h_bias")

    def propup(self, visible):
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(visible, self.weights) + self.h_bias)

    def propdown(self, hidden):
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden, tf.transpose(self.weights)) + self.v_bias)

    def sample_h_given_v(self, v_sample):
        return sample_prob(self.propup(v_sample))

    def sample_v_given_h(self, h_sample):
        return sample_prob(self.propdown(h_sample))

    def gibbs_hvh(self, h0_sample):
        v_sample = self.sample_v_given_h(h0_sample)
        h_sample = self.sample_h_given_v(v_sample)
        return [v_sample, h_sample]

    def gibbs_vhv(self, v0_sample):
        h_sample = self.sample_h_given_v(v0_sample)
        v_sample = self.sample_v_given_h(h_sample)
        return  [h_sample, v_sample]

    def cd1(self, visibles, learning_rate=0.1):
        h_start = self.propup(visibles)
        v_end = self.propdown(h_start)
        h_end = self.propup(v_end)
        w_positive_grad = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(visibles), h_start)
        w_negative_grad = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(v_end), h_end)
        update_w = self.weights.assign_add(learning_rate * (w_positive_grad - w_negative_grad))
        update_vb = self.v_bias.assign_add(learning_rate * tf.reduce_mean(visibles - v_end, 0))
        update_hb = self.h_bias.assign_add(learning_rate * tf.reduce_mean(h_start - h_end, 0))
        return [update_w, update_vb, update_hb]

    def reconstruction_error(self, dataset):
        err = tf.stop_gradient(dataset - self.gibbs_vhv(dataset)[1])
        return tf.reduce_sum(err * err)
```

---

**rbm_MNIST_test.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import rbm
import input_data

def build_model(X, w1, b1, wo, bo):
    h1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w1)+b1)
    model = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h1, wo)+bo)
    return model

def init_weight(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, mean=0.0, stddev=0.01))

def init_bias(dim):
    return tf.Variable(tf.zeros([dim]))

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 784])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10])

rbm_layer = rbm.RBM("mnist", 784, 500)

for i in range(10):
    print "RBM CD: ", i
    rbm_layer.cd1(trX)

rbm_w, rbm_vb, rbm_hb = rbm_layer.cd1(trX)


wo = init_weight([500,10])
bo = init_bias(10)
py_x = build_model(X, rbm_w, rbm_hb, wo, bo)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(py_x, Y))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cost)
predict_op = tf.argmax(py_x, 1)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(10):
    for start, end in zip(range(0, len(trX), 128), range(128, len(trX), 128)):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end]})
    print i, np.mean(np.argmax(teY, axis=1) ==
                     sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: teX, Y: teY}))
```

---

but here comes the error:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1626, in as_graph_def
>       raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.") ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.

Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 12):

TensorFlow does have a limit of 2GB on the `GraphDef` protos, which stems from a limitation of the protocol buffers implementation. You can quickly reach that limit if you have large constant tensors in your graph. In particular, if you use the **same** numpy array multiple times, TensorFlow will add multiple constant tensors to your graph.

In your case, `mnist.train.images` returned by `input_data.read_data_sets` is a numpy floating point array with shape `(55000, 784)`, so it is about `164 MB`. You pass that numpy array to `rbm_layer.cd1`, and inside that function, every time you use `visibles`, a TensorFlow `Const` node gets created from the numpy array. You use `visibiles` in 3 locations, so every call to `cd1` is increasing the graph size by approximately `492 MB`, so you easily exceed the limit. The solution is to create a TensorFlow constant once and pass that constant to the `cd1` function like so :

```
trX_constant = tf.constant(trX)
for i in range(10):
    print "RBM CD: ", i
    rbm_layer.cd1(trX_constant)
```

BTW, I am not sure what your intention is in the above loop. Note that the `cd1` function simply adds the `assign_add` nodes to the graph, and does NOT actually perform the assigns. If you really want those assigns to happen while you train, you should consider chaining those assigns via control dependencies to your final `train_op` node.

Answer (score 4):

To fulfill @keveman's question, I think you are trying to implement the `CD-k` (Contrastive Divergence) step by using that loop.

But I'm afraid the code is so far from appropriate since the `CD-k` is the function which should take the position of *Automatic Differentiation* in `RBM`. That means the `cost` and `train_op` is not the correct way to use with *Gradient Descent* in `RBM` (which is because of the special role of CD-k). By the way, the *RBM* layer should be trained one by one without *fully-connected layer* which is not in your code.

I'm new to tensorflow, and I also want to get the implementation. I think I'd rather not use *Gradient Descent* provided by tensorflow since I need `CD-k` for special differentiation. Wish I could find the solution soon.

**Update:**
I've worked on this implementation for a whole work day. So, here's the current status. I've implement a simple straightforward version but It just get wrong result.
Please refer to [code and result](https://gist.github.com/myme5261314/005ceac0483fc5a581cc)

I just refer the specific approach from [DeepLearnToolbox](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox). I think the procedure that I'm trying to implement through `tensorflow` is ok, but don't know what's going wrong about the practical code.

**Update 2:** I've revised the code and now I've implemented the simplest rbm through tensorflow. see `code and result` link above.