# Custom operation implementation for RBM/DBN with tensorflow?

Tags: theano, tensorflow, deep-learning, rbm, dbn

Since Google released out tensorflow, it becomes kind of trend in the current deep learning selections.

I'd like to do some experiments about RBM/DBN (Restricted Boltzmann Machine/Deep Belief Network), I've made some attempt by myself and kind of implement it well through the combination of available APIs from tensorflow. See [code](https://github.com/myme5261314/dbn_tf) and [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760981/rbm-implemention-with-tensorflow/35446666#35446666).

So, if doesn't bother the code running performance, here's the gift for RBM/DBN implementation with tensorflow.

But, the running performance must be considered for the future. Because of the special progress of CD (Contrastive Divergence) algorithm, I think it just works against the framework (data flow graph) used by tensorflow. That's why my **code** seems weired.

So, the custom operation should be implemented for acceleration. I've followed the current [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#implement-the-kernel-for-the-op) about adding custom ops.

```
REGISTER_OP("NaiveRbm")
    .Input("visible: float32")
    .Input("weights: float32")
    .Input("h_bias: float32")
    .Input("v_bias: float32")
    .Output("hidden: float32")
    .Doc(R"doc(
Naive Rbm for seperate training use. DO NOT mix up with other operations
)doc");
```

In my design, `NaiveRbm` should is an operation that takes `visible`,`weights`,`h_bias`,`v_bias` as input, but output by only **first** 3 `Variables` ( simply sigmoid(X*W+hb) ), its gradient should return at least gradients for **last** 3 `Variables`.

Imagine example psuedo code like this:

```
X = tf.placeholder()
W1, hb1, vb1 = tf.Variable()
W2, hb2, vb2 = tf.Variable()
rbm1 = NaiveRbm(X,W1,hb1,vb1)
train_op = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.01, 0.5).minimize(rbm1)
rbm2 = NaiveRbm(tf.stop_gradient(rbm1), W2, hb2, vb2)
train_op2 = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.01, 0.5).minimize(rbm2)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for batch in batches:
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch})
    for batch in batches:
        sess.run(train_op2, feed_dict={X: batch})
```

**But** the tensorflow library is too complex for me. And after too much time seeking for how to implement these existing operations (`sigmoid`, `matmul`, `ma_add`, `relu`, `random_uniform`) in custom operation, no solution is found by myself.

So, I'd like to ask if someone could help me achieve the remain works.

PS: before getting some ideas, I'd like to dive into `Theano` since it implements RBM/DBN already. Just in my opinion, `Caffe` is kind of not suitable for RBM/DBN because of its framework.

**Update**: After scratch through the tutorials from Theano, I found the key reason for Theano implemented the RBM/DBN while the tensorflow haven't is the `scan` technology. So, there might wait tensorflow to implement `scan` technology to prepare for RBM/DBN implementation.

Comment: So you mean to say that RBM and DBN can not be implemented in tensorflow? @myme5261314

Comment: You should be aware that this question was asked a year ago.

Comment: I am well aware of the fact that this is 1 year old post, but I didnt find your code updated or any other code which answers this question. So I thought you didnt succeeded

Comment: you should know that the core operation that supports the success of RBM is `scan`, you should take a look at that part in tensorflow now. At the time I open this question, there's no `scan` in tensorflow.